# How to turn this function into a dry function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a typewriter effect to my page and it works fine with predefined data but I'm unable to turn it into a function which receives values and then prints those values.

I've tried changing the original function by adding parameters and trying to print the values passed in but only the first letter is printed.

<-- This is the original function. -->

```
let i = 0;
let txt = 'Hello world';
let speed = 50;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += 
    txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}

typeWriter();
```

<-- This is what I have changed it to. -->

```
function typeWriter(id, text) {
  if (i < text.length) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += text.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}


typeWriter("text", "Hello world" );
```

The first letter is printed and the console prints this message "error"
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at typeWriter (xifoxoj.js:18:16)"

My expected value is that the text value passed into the function will be printed fully within the element with the id passed into the function but instead only the first letter of the text value is printed.

Comment: your error: well yeah, i isn't defined within the function scope

Comment: `setTimeout(typeWriter, speed)` You're not passing any parameters to `typeWriter`

Comment: This is being edited faster than being answered!

Comment: @Andreas has the correct answer. I'd suggest placing it as an answer to the question.

Comment: @Andreas When I pass in both id and text to typeWriter the text is printed all at once rather than one by one. Do you know how I can make it print each letter one at a time? Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasBrok I tried his answer prior to asking the question but his solution prints the whole text instead of printing each letter one by one which is what I'm looking to do.

Comment: Check the documentation of [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) and its optional parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a closure over `id` and `text` and call the returned function for a first call. Then any other needed calls are made by the timeout.

This approach shorts the string and ends with an empty string.

```js
function typeWriter(id, text) {
    return function () {
        if (text) {
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += text[0];
            setTimeout(typeWriter(id, text.slice(1)), speed);
        }
    };
}

var speed = 50;

typeWriter("text", "Hello world")();
```

```html
<span id="text"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you @NinaScholz your answer also works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Using String#split, Array#forEach.

*Note: increase the speed by `speed * i`*

```js
function typeWriter(id, text) {
  const speed = 500;
  const ele   = document.getElementById(id)
  text.split("").forEach((c,i)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      ele.innerHTML += c;
    }, speed*i);
  });
}


typeWriter("text", "Hello world");
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! your answer does exactly what I've been trying to do.